# Which reason would I use to recommend deletion of an obsolete answer in Low Quality Posts?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

When recommending a Low Quality Post for deletion, these are your options:

[image: LQP Reasons]

However, there are many times in which none of these reasons really correspond to the reason for which you would recommend deletion. For instance, an answer is no longer correct, given the introduction of new APIs or deprecation of older ones.

Wouldn't it be easier if there would be a text field where reviewers can give more details about why they recommend deletion of an answer/question?

Comment: good question, it is indeed not quite comfortable to work around this (I usually post a comment from outside of queue and then pick "no comments needed" option: feels quite weird)

Comment: _"For instance, an answer is no longer correct given the introduction of new APIs or deprecation of older ones."_ IMHO, That's not a reason to delete something. I'd edit it instead explaining that it's outdated.

Comment: Why not leave a comment and then click no comment necessary? or up vote an existing one and then click no comment necessary?

Comment: @JonasCz Agreed, except that I'd rather use a comment than an edit for this.

Comment: As @MichaelT said, I mostly do the same in such cases and always tries to give reason before casting vote to delete however if somehow I missed it then I comment it later by reviewing the history.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Comments can get lost at the end of a long comment thread, and nobody will see it.

Comment: To add to Servy's answer, i saw quite some answers that were deprecated by the new version of the library / framework. 

I saw often that when they have a lot of upvote someone would have edit it adding an information about the fact that the old solution is "deprecated from version x.y and now should be done like this : [snippet]". 

Or someone else added an answer/comment about the deprecation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> For instance, an answer is no longer correct given the introduction of new APIs or deprecation of older ones.

That's not a reason to delete an answer.  Answers are not deleted based on whether or not they are correct, or if they actually succeed in answering the question.

If the answer is simply *wrong* then you should be downvoting it, not flagging it or recommending deletion from the LQP queue.

Comment: ... of course, no one is ever using old frameworks where such answers are still good and valid and useful... as I return to working with a framework released in December 2011, and three major revisions behind current. There is hope though, with the next "lets update authorized libraries" push, it will go up to December 2013 for the framework release.

Comment: @Eric It is highly inappropriate to edit an answer into a completely different answer.  If you want to post your own answer, post your own answer; don't edit another person's answer, remove the entirety of it, and replace it with your own answer.

Comment: @Servy, if you take a deep breath and look at the [revisions history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/289576/revisions) I honestly don't see any significant way in which my edits *modified* your answer. They just clarified its meaning and provided links.

Comment: @Eric You added content about non-answers being deleted, despite this not at all being a non-answer, you removed information about how it should be acted on, which is exactly what the question is asking about, added a link to a post that has less relevant information than this answer, you removed a quote clarifying exactly what the answer is responding to, and finally changing text to be in your voice, and not mine, when there isn't anything wrong with what was there before, isn't appropriate.  Now if you want to make all of those changes in your own answer, I have no problem with that.